# tableView cells can't be selected with hitTest: WithEvent:

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a map and above it `UIScrollView` with a subview of an `UITableView` (there is a map and you can scroll the `tableView` up and down on the screen using the `scrollView`).

I'm using `-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to detect rather the user touches the `tableView` or the map in the background (if he's scrolling the `tableView` it will go up and down and if he's scrolling the map the map will change the position (like any regular map)).

The code:

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint comparePoint=CGPointMake(point.x, point.y-[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height+self.allCellsHeightDividedBy2);

    if (comparePoint.y<self.contentOffsetRecivied.y) {
        return nil;
    }

    return self;
}
```

It's all working fine but the problem is that you can't select a cell in the `tableView` for some reason, it just don't select it.

Does anybody have an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hitTest:withEvent:` is supposed to return the *deepest subview* which the point intersects with. Since you're only returning `self`, subviews can't be touched.

You should probably replace `return self;` with `return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event]`.

Comment: I'm using the function in a class I created that inherit from `UIScrollView' and it's the class of my `scrollView`, when I'm returning self I'm basically returning the `scrollView` and there is no superclass that can be relevant above it. The `tableView` is a subview of the `scrollView`. Do you understand what I done here and have any solution for me? Thanks!

Comment: @Yhper As you say, the superclass of your class is `UIScrollView`; it's `UIScrollView`'s implementation of `hitTest:withEvent:` that will be called when you use `[super hitTest:...]`. Did you try the solution I suggested in the second paragraph?

Comment: Wow! It worked! It didn't work the first time I tried it, maybe I copied it wrong the other time. Thank you so much!